# What's the name of the song that played in the last few minutes of episode 13 of Charlotte?

Tags: music, charlotte

It's towards the end of the episode, something about Sinking Ships but I can't find the song.

Answer (score 3):

「君の文字」 *Kimi no Moji* "Your Glyphs", sung by Kumaki Anri. It ought to be out as part of [the OST](http://vgmdb.net/album/53674) on 4 Nov 2015.

"Sinking Ships" is the one that starts at around 12:50 into the episode.