# What is the name of the ZHIEND song in the middle of episode 13?

Tags: music, charlotte

In episode 13 of Charlotte, there is a ZHIEND song playing about halfway in the episode, just before Yu in insane mode starts stealing other people's abilities, such as the bomb ability.

Comment: related: http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/26242/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Charlotte [wiki](http://charlotte-anime.wikia.com/wiki/ZHIEND) article on ZHIEND, the song is
**「Sinking Ship」**.

This track comes from their first Album: **「ECHO」**, released on October 14, 2015.

The CD can be bought through [Japanese Amazon](http://www.amazon.co.jp/ECHO-ZHIEND/dp/B012VTVM5Y) for 3780 yen.